NetBeans: Syntax-Highlighting JavaScript embedded in XML
I'm using Apache NetBeans 22 (Windows, all settings default).
I'd like to syntax highlight JavaScript code that is embedded in XML. The file extension is .xml. The JS-Code is embedded inside <js>-Tag and CDATA like this:
<js>
    <![CDATA[
        ${cursor}
    ]]>
</js>

How do I manage to get the JS syntax-highlighted in NetBeans 22?
